# registering a user in laravel 5 and send data to two tables, is this correct

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I am using this code to register a user in Laravel 5.1 getting also user details during registration and storing them in a second table (user_details). Do you think this is made correctly? It works but I am new to laravel and stuff and I'd like to see what others think.

What happens is the users table gets the name, email and passwords and the user_details table gets the rest of the data, then I return user so to automatic login as post registration.

Thanks to @Shanoop I modified the create function in authController.php to something like this:

```
protected function create(array $data)

    {

        $user = User::create([

            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),

        ]);

        $user_details = new User_Detail;

        $user_details->fill([

            'detail_1' => $data['detail_1'],
            'detail_2' => $data['detail_2'],
            'detail_3' => $data['detail_3'],

        ]);


        $user_details->save([$user]);

        return $user;


    }
```

Comment: It's *generally* a bad idea to split off one-to-one stuff like this. Why not put the user details in the user model?

Comment: the user detail model has one to many for every detail: //eloquent
    public function user(){
        return $this->hasMany('User');
    }

    public function detail_1(){
        return $this->hasMany('detail_1');
    }

    public function detail_2(){
        return $this->hasMany('detail_2');
    }

    public function detail_3(){
        return $this->hasMany('detail_3');
    }

Answer (score 0):

Laravel is really flexible and makes it really easy to update db data, so I believe you question is on whether data should be split into 2 tables or 1 -- correct me if I am wrong.

My rule of thumb is that if data has a one-to-one relationship, it belongs in the same table. Splitting it up into multiple tables will result in more complex or multiple queries to retrieve the information.

If the relationship is one-to-many or many-to-many, then splitting is the right way to go.

Keep in mind that there are exceptions to both rules, but they generally make the most sense.

Comment: hello, no the question regards 'Inserting Related Models' and if this is the way to go. Those details represent ids of other tables (they are all foreign keys).

Comment: of course many 1 to 1 relations belongs to one sample table, but it's not everytime, you need more information about the entities that you want to abstract into tables, on some cases put not related data on the same table is a bad idea, like put "account" info on the same table as "users" table, the problem becomes more bigger when you realize that on some cases some users will not have any account.
The way is considering your table on Third normal form but its too abstract, the way is asking yourselve if "the thing i wanna put here express the real object that i want to abstract?"

Answer (score 0):

**First** of all, i recomend you to use `Request` object, to get data from inputs sent by post.
a `Request` object will make easy your data management, before store them in the db.

**Second** if you define your `$fillable` variable on your model, it's not necesary to pass one by one the data.

your model:

```
class UserDetails extends model{
   protected $fillable = ["detail_1", "detail_2", "detail_3"];
}
```

your controller method:

```
$user_details = new UserDetails();
$user_details->fill($data); //laravel automatically take only 
                           //the vars defined on $fillable variable in your method
```

another and more simple example:

```
$user_details = new UserDetails($data); //laravel gonna call fill method when you pass a var in the constructor
```

However if you want to pass only the variables that you wanna fill, because you wanna be more secure about your vars, with `Request` object you can do this:

```
public update (Request $request){ 
    /*
     * when you pass a laravel object "Request", it gonna be filled automatically by laravel 
     */
    $user_details = new UserDetails();
    $user_details->fill( $request->only("details_1", "details_2") );
}
```

Third and finally:
**How to manage relations between tables**

**1.-** you need to define your tables in laravel convention (to be more easy), that means, your tables need to be declared like a plural subject in underscore convention, the table with a dependency need a foreign key, that var need to be named as your table on singular followed by: `_id`.

example:

```
users:
id, name

===============
user_details:
id, user_id, detail_1
```

**2.-** you need to declare your model

(if you are using composer the step 1 and 2 are easy with only call `php artisan make:model User` if you are using laravel 5.1 add `--migration` or `-m` to do a migration `php artisan make:model User -m`)

Your user model needs to have a relation 1 by 1 so check the documentation: [laravel relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#relationships)

your user model:

```
public class User extends Model{
    public function user_detail(){
       return $this->hasOne("App\UserDetail");
    }
}
```

your UserDetails model:

```
public UserDetail extends Model{
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo("App\User");
    }
}
```

so when you wanna store

```
$user = new User($data);
$user_details = new UserDetails($data);
$user->save();
$user->user_detail()->save($user_details);
```

Comment: Thanks for this info. On second thought I decided to avoid splitting the user table

Comment: very clever decision xD